# How can I separate the emoji only when the result is correct? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I separate the emoji only when the result is correct?

A random number that I type will show the same result with emojis. But, I only need the emoji when the result is correct. [image]

Only the emoji will appear when the answer is correct.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

looks like a scope issue.

```
document.getElementById('displayStar').innerHTML =...
```

should be inside the else condition, now it's showing both message and 'displayStar' regardless the condition because it's outside of the scope, this part of code will run anyway.

Comment: I don't get it. But I only need the emoji when my answer is correct.

Comment: right. what it means is, in the if(){}else if(){} else {} conditions, the code inside {} would run if the conditions are met accordingly, therefore showing-emoji-code should be in the else {}, so it'd only run if else happens. right now it's outside of all 3 {}, meaning it'd run anyway the conditions in 3 {} wouldn't matter to the showing-emoji-code. hope that makes sense